# Display text in datagridview cell instantly from the bound textbox while typing?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have bound the Text property of a textbox to a column of a data grid view like the following:

```
dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add("Name", textBox1, "Text");
```

I have tried to type something  text in the text box but the value of the cell in the column bound to `textBox1` (column `"Name"`) didn't reflect the text in the text box unless I clicked on the current cell and moved to other.

Is there any way to make it reflect the changes while typing in the text box?